# Flash video for Windows/VirtualDub/media player

Tags: codec, flv, virtualdub

I don't want to install any codec packs because I remember the last time I did it unwanted results occurred. (I think a codec didn't play nice with an application and was a known problem with the codec. I *think*).

I would like to open up Flash videos (.flv) in [VirtualDub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualDub). I have a plugin for VirtualDub I just need the codec now. I tried putting DLLs into the VirtualDub folder but that didn't solve the problem. How can I get a codec for VirtualDub to use to decompress Flash video files?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to install K-Lite Codec Pack; I know that you have said "I don't want to install any codec packs" but with this codec pack during installation you can deselect everything and install only the specific codecs that you want.

Before that you should open the .flv files with MediaInfo to know what are the codec needed for the specific .flv files that you have.